# import/order unable to recognise unnamed imports?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, eslint, eslint-plugin-import

The specific rule `import/order` from `eslint-plugin-import` does not seem to recognise the unnamed imports such as import `moment/locale/fr`: to clarify, I need to import moment like this (as the documentation seems to indicate), so I am trying to have it ordered among the other imports using the import/order rule:

```
'import/order': [
  'warn',
  {
    alphabetize: {
      caseInsensitive: false,
      order: 'asc',
    },
    groups: ['builtin', 'unknown', 'external', 'internal', 'parent', 'sibling', 'index', 'type'],
    'newlines-between': 'always',
    pathGroups: [
      {
        group: 'builtin',
        pattern: 'react',
        position: 'before',
      },
      {
        group: 'unknown',
        pattern: 'moment/locale/fr',
        position: 'before',
      },
    ],
    pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes: ['react'],
  },
],
```

Having that, I would expect the `moment/locale/fr` import to be placed right after the builtin imports. However, I don't get any error wherever I put this import.
Worse, when I "mistakenly" put this package in a middle of a group and skip lines, I get warnings about the lines skipped, but no autofix, so it really seems import/order does not recognise unnamed imports.

Does anyone know how I could have it to work?

For the record, I am using `eslint-plugin-import` v2.29.0.

Comment: from the docs: `Unassigned imports are ignored, as the order they are imported in may be important.` ref: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/order.md

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense! If you write it as a response, I'll mark your answer as the solution

Comment: done, made it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unassigned imports are ignored, as the order they are imported in may be important.` Source: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/order.md